# Cannot pull mapped value after the record is inserted

Tags: apex, map

This is an apex action used in a flow. I have the issue when the flow takes in multiple requests, but works fine for individual requests. I am trying to write the code in a way it can handle multiple request.

I have this piece of code that is in a if else condition. Here I am trying to create a map of the accountToLink and the equipmentRecord in the else condition and after when I do a system.debug on the EquipmentToAccountMap map variable I do see the expected result.

```
Map<Account, Equipment__c> EquipmentToAccountMap = new Map<Account, Equipment__c>();

    } else {
        accountToLink = createAccountRecordWithDataFromCaseVeteranDetailsSection(caseRecord);
        accountsList.add(accountToLink);
        Contact contactToLink = createContactRecordWithDataFromCaseVeteranDetailsSection(caseRecord);            
        contactsList.add(contactToLink);

        Equipment__c equipmentRecord = createEquipmentRecordWithDataFromCaseVeteranDetailsSection(caseRecord);
        equipmentsList.add(equipmentRecord);
        if (equipmentRecord != null) {
            EquipmentToAccountMap.put(accountToLink, equipmentRecord);
        }
        caseToEquipmentMap.put(caseRecord, equipmentRecord);
        caseRecordsToUpdate.add(caseRecord);
    }
```

Now after these I do an insert on the accountsList and try to link the equipment record to the account in the if condition below. Why is it I am getting a null on the equipment record when I do a get on the EquipmentToAccountMap map variable?

```
    insert accountsList;

        // Link the Equipment to the Account
        if (!EquipmentToAccountMap.isEmpty()) {
            for (Account account : accountsList) {
                System.debug('EquipmentToAccountMap: ' + EquipmentToAccountMap);
                Equipment__c equipmentRecord = EquipmentToAccountMap.get(account);
                System.debug('EquipmentToAccountMap.get(account): ' + EquipmentToAccountMap.get(account));
                System.debug('EquipmentToAccountMapValues: ' + EquipmentToAccountMap.values());
                System.debug('equipmentRecord: ' + equipmentRecord);
                equipmentRecord.AccountId__c = account.Id;
            }
        }
insert equipmentsList
```

Does the insert accountsList make any changes internally to the record?

This is what each of the above system.debug statement prints -

```
System.debug('EquipmentToAccountMap: ' + EquipmentToAccountMap);
prints - EquipmentToAccountMap: {Account:{Name=Second Case, Id=001OC000006rbBpYAI}=null}

System.debug('EquipmentToAccountMap.get(account): ' + EquipmentToAccountMap.get(account));
prints - EquipmentToAccountMap.get(account): null

System.debug('EquipmentToAccountMapValues: ' + EquipmentToAccountMap.values());
prints - EquipmentToAccountMapValues: (Equipment__c:{Name=Second Equipment})

System.debug('equipmentRecord: ' + equipmentRecord);
 prints - equipmentRecord: null
```

It is on this line equipmentRecord.AccountId__c = account.Id; i get the attempt to de-reference a null object error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the insert accountsList make any changes internally to the record?

Yes, inserting an SObject (or a list thereof) causes the instance(s) to be updated with the Id. That changes the value of that object's "hash", and will make it between hard and impossible to get the values out of a map.

Once you put something into a map as a key, it should *never* be modified.

The cheap and easy workaround here is to

- use `.clone()` to create a completely separate, independent instance of an SObject as you `put()` it as the key
- then use `.clone()` when trying to retrieve data from the map, after your insert DML is done (to strip out the Id that is automatically set)

The SObject `.clone()` method has 4 optional arguments. The important one is the first, `preserveId`, which defaults to false after API v22.0. Having that be false means that the Id (if present) is not copied over into the clone.

A better approach might be to create a helper method that creates a "key" SObject (which is just a subset of fields that you're sure will uniquely identify each record you'll pass to it). You'd call it when initially putting data into the map, as well as when you want to retrieve data from the map.

```
public Account createAccountKey(Account input) {
    // Making a new SObject instance is one way to ensure that there is a separate,
    //   independent instance of your SObject
    return new Account(
        Name = input.Name,
        Phone = input.Phone
    );
}

// a few lines later...

// Not storing the result of createAccountKey() greatly reduces the chance/temptation
//   to make changes (on purpose or by accident/consequence) to it
myMap.put(createAccountKey(myAccount), otherData);

insert accounts;

for(Account acct : accounts){ 
    Object otherData = myMap.get(createAccountKey(acct));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Derek for the speedy response. Can i request a code sample of what you mentioned on the answer.

Comment: @sumchans There's... not much to explain via code? You literally just need to change `accountToLink` to `accountToLink.clone()` when you put it into your map, and similarly add `.clone()` when you try to `.get()` from the map in your `for (Account account : accountsList) {` loop.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not able to make it work. I am trying to learn apex as fast as I can to create something next week in my new job also I have been trying to make this work since day before yesterday and I am completely burned out.

Comment: Would you be able to put in the context of my code please?

Comment: @ Derek your code definitely works and now it is another part that is not working, and that is the reason i got confused.